# Resize UINavigationController during transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I have a "ParentViewController" with a child `UINavigationController`. Its view has several subviews, including `[navigationController view]`.

I sometimes update layout constraints belonging to `[parentViewController view]`, causing the UINavigationController to resize, and it *usually* works.

It fails when the UINavigationController is mid-transition (i.e. pushing or popping one if its own child view controllers) when the constraints change. When this happens, the `[navigationController view]` itself is properly resized, but its topViewController's subviews are not.

(If I rotate to landscape and back again, the layout corrects itself.)

I've struggled to debug this further as of yet.

Comment: Try calling [topViewController.view setNeedsLayout];

Comment: Are you using auto layouts?

Comment: @JoshGafni My current workaround is to call `[navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]` (`[topViewController.view setNeedsLayout]` didn't seem to do the trick) inside `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`. It fixes my bug, but seems sub-optimal because I'm *always* calling `setNeedsLayout` even though it's *almost always* unnecessary.

Comment: @Satyam `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is NO for all the subviews of `parentViewController.view`.